# update field does not load value in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

In my view, I have a dropdown field and a text box. This varies dynamically. This is working fine. It accepts value and stores, But when I do Update, the value is retrieved from Db, but not populating in the respective box.

My View:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
<tr>            
    <td>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'cm_classification_id'); ?>        
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'cm_classification_id', CHtml::listData(masterClassification::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'cm_classification_id ASC', 'condition'=>'cm_classification_type=:type', 'params'=>array('type'=>'initiate'))), 'cm_classification_id', 'cm_classification_name'),  array('empty'=>'Select classification')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'cm_classification_id'); ?>
    </td>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <label>Change Description <span class="required" id="desc_req_note" style="display:none;">*</span></label>
    <span id="cm_desc_select" style="display:none;"><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'cm_description',array(),array('empty'=>'Select Change Description')); ?></span>
     <span id="cm_desc_input" style="display:none;"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'cm_description1'); ?></span>
    <?php //echo $form->dropDownList($model,'cm_description',array(),array('empty'=>'Select Change Description')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'cm_description'); ?>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(cm_desc_select).show();
});
    $('#CMMaster_cm_classification_id').change(function(){

     var val = $(this).val();
     var cm_desc_select_elem = $('#cm_desc_select'); 
     var cm_desc_input_elem = $('#cm_desc_input');
     if(val != 3) 
     { 
         $(cm_desc_input_elem).show();
         $(cm_desc_select_elem).hide();
     } 
     else 
       { 
         $(cm_desc_select_elem).show();
         $(cm_desc_input_elem).hide();
        }
});</script>
```

My Action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
}
```

the classification field loads automatically from DB, but Description field has empty value through the data is fetched from DB.

Function:

```
public function loadModel($id) {
        $model = CMMaster::model()->findByPk($id);
        if ($model === null)
            throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }
```

Comment: Are you passing `$model` in your `actionUpdate($id)` ?

Comment: $model fetches the values from loadModel function of the same controller

Comment: In the `actionUpdate()` how do you render the view? Are you using `$this->render` or `$this->renderPartial`. If you are rendering the view then you have to pass the model like `$this->render('YOUR_VIEW', array('model'=>$model));`

Comment: I am passing the same, $this->render('update', array('model' => $model));  But same error

Comment: Ok do one thing. Change `$model->save();` to `if(!$model->save(){ echo '<pre>'; print_r($model->getErrors(); die('<pre>'); }` and see if the model is actually saved or it returns any error.

Comment: It gives me Validation Error "Change description cannot be blank"

Comment: Yes so that means your model is not saved. Make sure the attribute that is related to the description must not be blank. if you need any help with that, I have to see the complete `actionUpdate()` code as will as the attributes which are being validated.

Comment: but this is not I want, already there is input fetched from DB . but this value is not getting accomodated in change description field

Comment: Ok. that is because your change description dropdownlist is empty. `<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'cm_description',array(),array('empty'=>'Select Change Description')); ?>` you have to do it like: `<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'cm_description',CHtml::listData(MODEL_NAME::model()->findAll(),ATTRIBUTE_ID, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE),array('empty'=>'Select Change Description')); ?>`. Fill the `MODEL_NAME`, `ATTRIBUTE_ID` and `ATTRIBUTE_VALUE` accordingly then it will show

Comment: can you please add this discussion to chat, I cant do the same because I don't have reputation points

Comment: whenever the page is loaded, the data from DB fills automatically through AJAX. So is this also to be done by the same?

Comment: If the same dropdownlist is generated through ajax after the page is loaded then it won't work. because the php is already executed on the server. If this is the case then you have to use jquery to select the value.

Comment: You can change the `success` part of ajax as then `$('#DROPDOWN_ID').val('<?php echo $model->cm_description; ?>');`

Comment: its is not about the drop-down,Ill explain the scenario, If change_caetogory 1 is clicked -> change_description becomes a textbox, and when change_category is 2, change_description is a drop-down. When I update a entry, the value ie in DB is not getting accomodated in the change_description field

Comment: If `cm_description` is the change_description field that you are talking about then you have to populate the dropdownlist for the descriptions to show (which is currently empty & you say you populate it through ajax then you have to find a way to select the right change_description. And you don't need to use `cm_description1` for the textfield. You can use the same attribute as `cm_description` and it will have the same record. Then as I can see from your jquery you hide and show these field accordingly which is fine.

Comment: Finally I made it through JQuery. $('#DROPDOWN_ID').val('<?php echo $model->cm_description; ?>'); thanks man. there was an id misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#DROPDOWN_ID').val('<?php echo $model->cm_description; ?>');
```

It is done using JQuery in View.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not clear, but let's assume you are reading the dropdown data from the the cmm_master table.

In your form, change

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList(
         $model,
         'cm_description',
         array(),        // <=== You are not passing data //
         array('empty'=>'Select Change Description'));
?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,
         'cm_description',
          CHtml::listData(CMMaster::model()-‌​>findAll(),'cmm_id', 'cm_description'),
          array('empty'=>'Select Change Description'));
```

?>